# how to avoid Unclosed counted closure exception in a Dynamic Strings

Tags: java

I have an api which provides me the String like this

```
My name is {1 ABC#jsjsjsjsjsjsj~=DEF#jsjsjsjsjsjsj~GHI} I am living at {1=ABC#jsjsjsjsjsjsj~DEF~GHI}
```

so I need to replace the Strings within {} by some other String.

Basically I prepare a map with the `{1:SHORTANSWER:ABC#jsjsjsjsjsjsj~=DEF#jsjsjsjsjsjsj~GHI}`

and

`{1:SHORTANSWER:=ABC#jsjsjsjsjsjsj~DEF~GHI}`

so that at the time of the result I can replace this String with my desired String but I get error at "=" I am using

```
originalStringFromapi.replaceAll(map.getKey(),map.getValue());
```

In simple terms I generate a key by taking braces part from the string prepare a map with that key and at the end of my process I need to substitute the braces part of the string i.e key of map with the value. And form a new string similar to original one but the braces {} are gone and substituted by some other string that comes from maps value.

Comment: You cannot modify the original String because Strings are immutable. `replaceAll` returns a new String

Comment: I know that already..!!

Comment: then what are you asking? You said *"by not modifying the original String"*

Comment: In simple terms I generate a key by taking braces part from the string prepare a map  with that key and at the end of my process I need to substitute the braces part of the string i.e key of map with the value. And form a new string similar to original one but the braces {} are gone and substituted by some other string that comes from maps value

Comment: You need to escape the first argument of `replaceAll()` with `Pattern.quote()`..

Comment: Saka1029 it worked thanks a ton..!!